# How can I combine a datepart and a literal in a SQL Where clause?

Tags: sql

What I'm trying to do is select * from a date field where the start date is 9-1-last year and end date is 8-31-current year, but I don't want to make the year specific.

```
Select * from dbo."TABLE"
where (Date_Field) between  (year(DATEADD(year,-1, getdate())) +'09-01')  and ((YEAR( getdate())) +'08-31')
```

I get an "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int" error.

Comment: What do you mean by `last year`?

Comment: sorry, previous year. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom H got it right. SQL server is smart enough to cast the date from string  though, so

```
SELECT * from dbo."TABLE" 
WHERE (Date_Field) BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(DATEADD(year, - 1, 
GETDATE()))) + '-09-01' AND CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(GETDATE())) + '-08-31'
```

would suffice. More importantly you missed the leading `-` in `-09-01` and that's probably what thrown you off the track here.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you. The only change I had to make was removing the last ) after '-08-31'

Comment: copy/paste ;) I'll edit it out. Thank you for the rep!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that you're trying to combine an integer and a string and then you're trying to use them as a date. You need to explicitly `CAST` your data types in many cases. Also, you're missing the hyphen between the year and the rest of your date.

```
WHERE <date_field> BETWEEN
    CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AS CHAR(4)) + '-09-01' AS DATETIME) AND
    CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4)) + '-08-31' AS DATETIME)
```

You can also do this without any data type conversions by using date functions and some math:

```
BETWEEN
    DATEADD(DAY, 30, DATEADD(MONTH, 7, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0))) AND
    DATEADD(MONTH, 8, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))
```